# Google Sheet Query with Importrange and Date today

Tags: google-sheets

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx-Sheet-ID"; "Tabelle1!A:D"), 
"where C > date'" & text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' 
and D < date'" & text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'", 0)
```

Can someone told me, why this is not working?

I will get the row informations where the C date is smaller and the D date is bigger than today date.

I the table where i look is this formation `2021-03-29`of date

I tried this code above but this is not working... It says ERROR! but i dont see any logs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you granted permission to pull data from other spreadsheets, try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx-Sheet-ID"; "Tabelle1!A:D"); "where C > date '"& text(today(); "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and D < date '"& text(today(); "yyyy-mm-dd") &"'"; 0)
```

and see if that works? If not, please share a copy of your spreadsheet (sensitive data erased) so we see how your data is structured.

Note that importrange is only needed if you import data from ***another*** spreadsheet. Data imports from within the ***same*** spreadsheet can be done without it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace C by Col3 and D by Col4 (you can't use A, B, C and D in that case)

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("___________","Tabelle1!A:D"), "where Col4 > date '"& text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col3 < date '"& text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd") &"'", 0)
```

switch Col3 and Col4 as necessary